# Checking heartbeat of application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, webserver, background-process, heartbeat

I want to implement the heartbeat for my application.
In this module, my iOS app will send byte of data to my server at regular intervals.
I need this as the server wants the ack from device for being in touch with server when it sends a request.

Problem: If the application is quitted by user how will the heart-beat (byte of data) will be send to the server.

Comment: Your ability to run in the background on iOS is intentionally limited to certain tasks. I don't think you can do exactly what you describe. I'd look into using push notifications to send notifications to your app on iOS devices.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do it is register your application as *VoIP type* (the most problematic part, because if your app is not a *messenger/conference/social* type app Apple may refuse it) and then use `NSStream` in couple with `NSInputStream`/`NSOutputStream` and `<NSStreamDelegate>` interface to send/receive heartbeat.

Comment: Really thanks for your reply.. I was aware of this option, but what if the app is not running in background too?

Comment: You can use same connection (StreamSocket) to send data in active and background execution.

Comment: SOrry dear, I repeat... the app is not running, i.e. neither in active state nor in background.... It is just installed.. So how can I interact with the server?

Comment: Sorry, no idea of how do this... as i understand you want to do something like background non disableable agent on WP7.